# How is this correct?

Tags: number-theory, functional-equation

How is the following equation is correct?
$29$ - $1$ = $30$

**Hint-**

> Think Ancient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've got it :

> If I write your equation with roman numerals, it gives : XXIX - I = XXX.
>  Which is true if we consider `-` as `without`.

Got to say the hint helps a lot

Comment: Beat me by only 52 seconds... Ugh, good job anyways! :)

Comment: Don't worry at least you are right.

Answer (score 5):

> If you write out the equation in Roman numerals, you get XXIX - I = XXX, which makes sense when you interpret it as a word equation.